# PHP random link without repetitions

Tags: php, random

My PHP is poor, but I'm trying my best to improve!!

I'm attempting to code a really simple php script that loads a random  html page from a text file list.

Once people have viewed the html page, they link back to the random.php file and it loads another page... this can continue on forever.

I'm using a text file list as I'll regularly be adding more pages.  My issue is there is no where in my code to prevent repeat visits!!  Right now I only have about 8 links, and on more than one occasion I've had the same link 'randomly' come up 3 times in a row :(  Hoping there is something simple I can add to this to prevent repetitions, and if all links have been viewed, then it resets.  Many Thanks :)

```
    <body>

    <?php
    $urlist=file("randomlinks.txt");
    $nl=count($urlist);
    $np=rand(0,$nl-1);
    $url=trim($urlist[$np]);
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
    ?>

    </body>
```

Comment: Try using `mt_rand` instread of `rand`. `mt_rand` generate a better random value.

Answer (score 2):

Since the user does not know in what order the links are in the text file, if you were to read said links in sequence they would seem "random" (and you can shuffle them when first creating the file).

So you can:

- save in session the index of the last link seen
- link the link index to system time. This does not prevent repetitions, but guarantees that no two links come out equal, unless you hit 'refresh' after exactly the right amount of time.

**Method 1:**

```
$urlist=file("randomlinks.txt");
$nl=count($urlist);

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['link'])) // If link is not in session
    $_SESSION['link'] = 0;    // Start from 0 (the first)
$np = $_SESSION['link']++;    // Next time will use next
$_SESSION['link'] %= $nl;     // Start over if nl exceeded

$url=trim($urlist[$np]);
Header("Location: $url");
```

**Method 2:**

```
...
$nl=count($urlist);
$np = time() % $nl;           // Get number of seconds since the Epoch,
                              // extract modulo $nl obtaining a number that
                              // cycles between 0 and $nl-1, every $nl seconds
$url=trim($urlist[$np]);
Header("Location: $url");
```

Another method would be to remember the last N links seen - but for this, you *need* a session variable - so as not to get them again too soon.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['urlist']))       // Do we know the user?
    $_SESSION['urlist'] = array();     // No, start with empty list
if (empty($_SESSION['urlist']))        // Is the list empty?
{
    $_SESSION['urlist'] = file("randomlinks.txt");   // Fill it.
    $safe = array_pop($_SESSION['urlist']);
    shuffle($_SESSION['urlist']);           // Shuffle the list
    array_push($_SESSION['urlist'], $safe);
}
$url = trim(array_pop($_SESSION['urlist']));
```

If you have five URLS 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, you might get:

```
1 5 3 4 2 1 4 2 5 3 1 2 3 5 4 1 4 3 2 5 1 4 ...
```

...the list is N-1 random :-), all links appear with equal frequency, and the same link may reappear at most at a 2-remove, like the "4" above (...4 1 4...); if it does, you'll never see it again for at least `$nl` visits.

**ALSO**

1. You should not use `Header()` from within a `<BODY>` tag. Remove `<BODY>` altogether.
2. You don't need to use `exit()` if you are at the natural end of the script: the script will exit by itself.

Comment: Lsemi - Thank you for your input.  From what I can understand from your first method; If the user re-visits my site the following day, they'll have to look at all the links again in the same order.  I'd want it to always be random, just the links wont be repeated until they've all been viewed, or at worst, the same link wont repeat twice in a row.  Best.

Comment: Hmm. I'll add a third method :-)

Comment: Thank's again for your help.  Your third method looks like exactly what I'm after.  I've also removed the body tags and exit, so the PHP script comes after </head> and before the end of </html>

Only one problem.. the script doesn't seem to be working!! I've copied it exactly from your post... anything I'm missing?  Best.

Comment: (Just realised I fortgot to include the 'header'!! Silly me.. Seems to be working, thank you so much)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it really works. And it *should not* work, because `Header()` usually requires removing *everything* -- not only `<body>` but all other tags too. Your script should be 100% PHP, and no HTML. On some systems output buffering will make it work, but on some others it will complain!

Comment: so, the start of the document should be <?php

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of would be to use a cookie.

The Internet is full of tutorials such as the following:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

For example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["vistList"]))
  $visited = split(","$_COOKIE["visitList"]);
  foreach ($visited as &$value) {
    if ($value == /* new site url */) {
      //Find a new one
    }
  }
else
  $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
  setcookie("vistList", "List-of-visited-URLs, separated-by-commas", $expire);
?>
```

I have not had a chance to test this code, but hopefully it can give you ideas.

As noted in the comments, the same thing could be accomplished using php sessions:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["vistList"]))
  $visited = split(","$_SESSION["visitList"]);
  foreach ($visited as &$value) {
    if ($value == /* new site url */) {
      //Find a new one
    }
  }
else
  $_SESSION['vistList']=/* new site URL */
?>
```

Comment: or php sessions, a cookie is limited in the amount of data it can hold

Comment: cscot.  Thanks for your answer.  PHP sessions seem ideal, however with your code (from what I can understand), one must input the list of links within the code.  As I mentioned, I'll regularly be uploading the list of links to a text file.  Unless you feel your way is more efficient?  Many Thanks.

Comment: My code was intended to supplement your code. Since you already had code to determine a url, my code was just to check if it was original, and if so to add it to the cookie or session data before using it. By adding the links you had already seen, you would, given enough repetition, generate the data found in the text file, but it would never need to be in the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would use PHP sessions to do this. Take a look at [this example](http://codepad.org/W8E37r8P).

Store an array of available pages in a session variable. Every time you get a page, you remove that page from the array. When the array is empty, you reset it again from your original source.

Here's what your code might look like:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION["pages"]))
    $_SESSION["pages"] = file("randomlinks.txt");

$nl = count($_SESSION["pages"]);
$np = mt_rand(0, $nl-1);

// get the page, remove it from the array, and shift all higher elements down:
list($url) = array_splice($_SESSION["pages"], $page, 1);

die(header("Location: $url"));
```

Comment: There is a 1/$nl probability that the last link remaining before reload will be the same chosen after reload, though. I had to adopt an awkward solution to that :-(

Comment: Well, I'm not sure just how picky the OP is going to be about that. It took me a minute to understand what you meant, so to clarify for anyone else: there is a possibility with this solution that you could be on the last page of the list, which is when the list resets. When the list resets, it's possible for any page to be chosen (including the one you're currently on). So on the last page, there is a 1 in $nl chance that the next page will be the same one).

Comment: Now I've got to decide which scipt is more efficent.. Travesty3's or lserni's !? :p

Comment: I'm betting that any difference in performance will be negligible. You're only doing this once each time the user clicks on a link. I would bet that there will be no visible difference.